# Spring Boot using save never inserts a row inside of a Postgresql table

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

1. Problem Summary:

I cannot save a new entry inside of my table. I followed a few tutorials before I decided to try doing this task, and everything worked. I managed to do the following tutorial perfectly while also using PostgreSQL https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-flyway-database-migration-example/

The problem happened when I started using both a WebController and RestController. Using the controller.save() method isn't adding a new row.
When I try to run it I get the following error

```
ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "joke_pkey"
Detail: Key (id)=(1) already exists.

Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [com.example.joke4u.Joke#1]; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [com.example.joke4u.Joke#1]] with root cause
```

2. What I’ve tried:

Before anyone says it, I read somewhere that its bad practice to have both controllers in the same app but I have to do it this way because that is what my task requires me to do.
I've tried researching around but I couldn't find anyone else with the same error.
I even tried specifying an ID that is clearly not in use but that just updates the last row.

I tried using both (obv not both at the same time)

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
```

and

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
```

Neither of them changes the outcome

3. Code:

application.properties :

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/flyway_demo
spring.datasource.username=bob
spring.datasource.password=bob123

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
```

My Web Controller that has the post function:

```
@PostMapping("/post")
public String insertJoke(JokeForm jokeForm) {
    int categoryid = jokeForm.getCategoryId();
    String content = jokeForm.getContent();
    databasController.insert(categoryid, content);
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

My DBController whose insert function is being called"

```
public Joke insert(int categoryid, String content) {
    return jokeRepository.save(new Joke(categoryid, content));
}
```

Full Joke data class:

```
@Entity
public class Joke {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
@Column(columnDefinition = "serial")
private long id;

@NotNull
private int categoryid;

@NotBlank
private String content;

@Column(columnDefinition = "integer default 0")
private int likes = 0;

@Column(columnDefinition = "integer default 0")
private int dislikes = 0;

public Joke() {
}

public Joke(int categoryid, String content) {
    this.setCategoryid(categoryid);
    this.setContent(content);
}

public Joke(long id, int categoryid, String content) {
    this(categoryid, content);
    this.id = id;
}

//id
public long getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

// categoryid
public int getCategoryid() {
    return this.categoryid;
}

public void setCategoryid(int categoryid) {
    this.categoryid = categoryid;
}

// content
public String getContent() {
    return this.content;
}

public void setContent(String content) {
    this.content = content;
}

// likes
public int getLikes() {
    return this.likes;
}

public void setLikes(int likes) {
    this.likes = likes;
}

public void incrementLikes() {
    ++likes;
}

public void decrementLikes() {
    --likes;
}

// dislikes
public int getDislikes() {
    return this.dislikes;
}

public void setDislikes(int dislikes) {
    this.dislikes = dislikes;
}

public void incrementDislikes() {
    ++dislikes;
}

public void decrementDislikes() {
    --dislikes;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "{" + " id='" + getId() + "'" + ", categoryid='" + getCategoryid() + "'" + ", content='" + getContent()
            + "'" + ", likes='" + getLikes() + "'" + ", dislikes='" + getDislikes() + "'" + "}";
}}
```

Joke Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface JokeRepository extends JpaRepository<Joke, Integer> {
   Joke findById(long id);
   List<Joke> findByCategoryid(int categoryid);
}
```

Edit:
I found some good news! I can insert into my database, as many rows as I want, but only if I don't insert anything using a data.sql file. The task requires me to do so though :(

Comment: I believe this is the problem `GenerationType.TABLE` try some other strategy like `GenerationType.AUTO`

Comment: Sorry, I should've said I tried this already. I initially had it on GenerationType.AUTO but then I found someone with a similar issue and someone recommended using.TABLE instead. I just tried to put it back to AUTO hoping I actually fixed the issue by now but no... even with AUTO it's still the same.

Comment: Joke.id is not auto-generated, but explicitly set (in your controller) ..and obviously to a conflicting value...Solutions: a) clean up data base. b) choose an other id (in your form). c) set no id at all (if you want to "test" auto-generation).

Comment: Thank you for your ideas. I tried cleaning my base a few times. It is true however that I start off with initializing the database every time. But the problem is, I never set the id for Joke. How is my joke.id not autogenerated I only set the content of it and the categoryid inside of the controller.

Comment: Are you setting Joke.id in your data.sql inserts because that's where it would make sense you are messing this up. Your inserts from data.sql are not using up your autogenerated ids.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar case.

What I did was using

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE
```

Then in my data.sql file I used the Sequence to add the data. This increments the sequence.

This is for postgreSQL:

```
INSERT INTO joke(id, categoryid, content )
VALUES (nextval('hibernate_sequence'), 1, 'joke');
```

Comment: Hey, someone else helped me. Thank you so much for responding. The real answer was to change it to GenerationType.IDENTITY. I didnt even need to add that nextval('hibernate_sequence') part.

Comment: Ok nice.I remember now why I user sequence. It is an optimization. You can read about it here https://thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-postgresql-5-things-need-know/

Answer (score 0):

Someone helped me get to my answer. I am so incredibly thankful. The solution is here. 
[Cannot use save() to insert when previously importing data using data.sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60932169/cannot-use-save-to-insert-when-previously-importing-data-using-data-sql)

If you dont want to go there and just want to fix it. What fixed it for me was just changing the GenerationType, not to AUTO or TABLE or SEQUENCE, but to IDENTITY.