# Cannot use save() to insert when previously importing data using data.sql

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm terribly sorry if I can't start another post which is connected to my previous one but my question is somewhat different.

I noticed that I really can save new data in my database as long as I never added data to the database by using the line `spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always` in my application.properties and made a data.sql file with a few insert statements. Once I insert the data using that file, I can access the data and show it to the user, but I can't create any new data because I get the following error

```
ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "joke_pkey"
Detail: Key (id)=(1) already exists.
```

Does anyone know how to help me with this? I'm doing an interview task and I am meant to first import data using the data.sql file and then later add some more data.

The post with my code is here:
[Spring Boot using save never inserts a row inside of a Postgresql table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60918840/spring-boot-using-save-never-inserts-a-row-inside-of-a-postgresql-table)

**EDIT** - someone recommended adding my code here directly and saying what I've tried.

*I have tried* to initialize the database with the application properties the way they are, then restarting the app but without the last line, and setting the `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` to `none`. But even so, it didn't work. I genuinely expected it to work like that. Because if the table is empty and I fill it in using the functions I created, everything works like a charm, even after restarting the server (id keep the `ring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` to `none` again to keep the data from being deleted)

I have also tried simply changing the `GenerationType.AUTO` to `GenerationType.TABLE` strategy in my Joke class, but that didn't seem to change anything either.

application.properties :

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/flyway_demo
spring.datasource.username=bob
spring.datasource.password=bob123

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
```

My Web Controller that has the post function:

```
@PostMapping("/post")
public String insertJoke(JokeForm jokeForm) {
    int categoryid = jokeForm.getCategoryId();
    String content = jokeForm.getContent();
    databasController.insert(categoryid, content);
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

My DBController whose insert function is being called

```
public Joke insert(int categoryid, String content) {
    return jokeRepository.save(new Joke(categoryid, content));
}
```

Most of my Joke data class:

```
@Entity
public class Joke {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(columnDefinition = "serial")
private Long id;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "category_id_FK")
private long categoryId;

@NotBlank
private String content;

@Column(columnDefinition = "integer default 0")
private int likes = 0;

@Column(columnDefinition = "integer default 0")
private int dislikes = 0;

public Joke() {
}

public Joke(long categoryid, String content) {
    this.setCategoryid(categoryid);
    this.setContent(content);
}

// id
public Long getId() {
    return this.id;
}

// id
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

// categoryid
public long getCategoryid() {
    return this.categoryId;
}

public void setCategoryid(long categoryid) {
    this.categoryId = categoryid;
}

// content
public String getContent() {
    return this.content;
}

public void setContent(String content) {
    this.content = content;
}

// likes
public int getLikes() {
    return this.likes;
}

public void setLikes(int likes) {
    this.likes = likes;
}

// dislikes
public int getDislikes() {
    return this.dislikes;
}

public void setDislikes(int dislikes) {
    this.dislikes = dislikes;
}

}
```

Joke Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface JokeRepository extends JpaRepository<Joke, Integer> {
   Joke findById(long id);
   List<Joke> findByCategoryid(int categoryid);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that all you need to do is change GenerationType.AUTO to GenerationType.IDENTITY.

Reason behind this is the sequence, which might be out of sync if you use AUTO. Because then hibernate uses its own sequence instead of the one postgres creates when using serial.

Comment: Sorry, i assumed you would click the link and see my code and see what I've tried. I will add the code now and add some things I've tried.

Comment: Well if im not wrong the issue is with the sequence. GenerationType.AUTO lets hibernate create its own sequence. I would suggest you use the sequence postgresql creates for every serial you define and tell hibernate to use that sequence (by using identity instead of auto and tell hibernate which sequence to use). This way hibernate does not create its own sequence. Because having postgres sequence in use by manually insert data and hibernates sequence causes sync issues like you have. Just two sequences which are not in sync

Comment: phaen, I swear I spent longer than 15 hours on this, going back and forth trying loads of different things and googling for ages. You have no idea how grateful I am. I will mark this as the answer, if you don't mind though, could you just write that on the original comment of yours that it is needed to change GenerationType.AUTO to GenerationType.IDENTITY.
I dont know who you are or where you are, but I want you to know, you made someone incredibly happy with your comment today. Thank you so so so so much!